# algorithmicx - How to change "Procedure" to "def"

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic

I am using `algorithmicx`. It gives a block using `\Procedure`.
However, I want to make my presentation of algorithms in python style,
since I implemented it in python.

In python, to define a function, we write `def func_name(arg) :`.
There is no corresponding `end def`.
I know one can create customized block, but I didn't figure it out.

The `if` is not with a `then` but just with a colon, e.g. `if (a > 0) :`,
and there is no corresponding `end if`.

Also, I want to change the comment into python style, which starts with `#`.

Thank you if someone can help me, please.

Comment: `algorithmicx` is mostly used for pseudocode, if you want to include snippets of Python then maybe the package `listings` is a better choice (it comes with syntax highlighting for many languages, including Python).